# ОС не запускается, удалены "*" разделы

Tags: windows-7, partition

Вкратце:

Когда запускаю ПК, он быстро показывает общую информацию о себе, а затем переходит к экрану, где показывает носители, и говорит, что это займет пару секунд.

Но, к несчастью, на этом моменте он зависает, и может ничего не делать веками, хоть я и могу нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, и он сделает всё заново (но даже это сочетание он поймёт не более двух раз за один запуск, а иногда и вовсе безразличен к нему).

Про ПК:

- на SSD стоит Windows7
- ПК древний (старше 2008 года)
- материнская плата - `Gigabyte GA-965P-S3`
- SSD - `Crucial CT240M500SSD1`

Предистория:

У меня было 2 раздела на SSD, но хотел себе сделать третий для другой ОС. Использовал `PAssist` для деления имеющихся разделов. В какой-то момент поторопился и приказал удалить созданные ранее системой `*` разделы. Программа в режиме ПреОС выполняла действия, а затем заявила об ошибке, и сказала, что компьютер надо перезапустить вручную если он сам того не сделает. Через 10 минут перезапускаю и попадаю в описаную ранее ситуацияю.

Доволнительно:

- Пробовал использовать установочный USB-флеш-накопитель с `Ubuntu 16.04`, но не помогает (впрочем, у меня нет возможности проверить, что флешка действительно работает как установочная).
- Не удаётся зайти в BIOS. При запуске ПК внизу экрана сказано, что для запуска BIOS нужно нажать клавишу <kbd>Del</kbd>. Если усердно нажимать её, то надпись измениться на `Prepare to Enter Setup`, но далее всё как раньше. Аналогично с нажатием <kbd>F12</kbd> для `Boot menu`.
- пробовал загрузочный диск с Ubuntu 16.10 - тот же результат.
- Еще заметил, что во время POST слышно привычный одиночный "пик", но за ним следует более короткий и тихий, который отсутствовал при нормальной работе.

Вопросы:

- Есть ли возможность вернуть всё как было?
- ..Или хотя бы поставить другую ОС поверх имеющихся на SSD данных?

Готов дополнить вопрос необходимой информацией.

**Обновление**:

По совету @Akina отсоединил все девайсы SATA. При запуске ПК он их не обноружил, но в конце концов вывел список PCI девайсов и сказал `DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER`. После перезагрузки оказалось возможным попасть в БИОС. Обнаружил интересную особенность: если подсоединить SATA девайс (например дисковод) в перед (по нумерации портов) SSD, то ПК увидит его, но на этом остановится, даже если после SSD подключить еще какой-то девайс.

**Обновление**:

1. Попытался зайти в `Boot Menu` - клавиатура отказывалась переключаться между варианта, хотя <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> подействовало.
2. Зашол в BIOS - изменил приорет загрузки и поставил дисковод первым. Втсавил диск с `Ubuntu 16.10` и выбрал `Try Ubuntu`. Далее ПК вывел множественное сообщение об ошибки чтения блока в `sdb`.
3. Перезапускаю - ПК не видит загрузочный диск (который запустил 3 минуты назад).
4. Перезапуск. Захожу в `Boot Menu` - ПК теперь реагирует на нажатия стрелок на клавиатуре. При выборе диска опять пишет `DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER`.

Comment: Зависает скорее всего начальный загрузчик - повреждён, видимо. Windows 7 поверх ставить вполне можно. Правда, есть риск потерять документы - так что лучше снять доки, а потом реформат и чистая установка.

Comment: @Akina а как "снять доки"?

Comment: Загрузиться в другой инстанс ОС (LiveCD или загрузочная флешка) и скопировать все нужные файлы на внешний носитель.

Comment: @Akina не работает установочный диск. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Возьмите Windows PE (скажем, PE10_8 by Sergey Strelec, или хотя бы PE Mini WIM Edition). Сделайте загрузочную флешку (например, используя UTMake). Проверьте её на работоспособность с помощью QEmu. И грузитесь. Но что не попадаете в настройки БИОС - странно... проверьте, что будет, если убрать из системы SSD. Может, это матерь нездорова...

Comment: @Akina 1. доступны ли указанные Вами программы для работы с диском? (биос старый и флешек не понимает). 
2. Попробовал отключить дисковод, SSD и жесткий диск - на 2 экране (на котором ранее останавливался запуск)  пк сказал что девайсов не обнаружено (что, кстати, часто случалось и при нормальной работе), и на 4 экране сказал `DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER`

Comment: 1) Если БИОС не понимает флешек - грузитесь с проверенного (!) загрузочного CD/DVD-диска. 2) Отключив SSD (остальное отключать необязательно), проверьте, попадаете ли в BIOS Setup. Если да - выполните Load Defaults, подключите обратно SSD и пробуйте опять попасть в БИОС сетуп. Да, и назовите точную модель SSD и модель/ревизию материнской платы.

Comment: @Akina 1. как же проверить диск? Я поставил свой в полурабочий ноут - до экрана выбора "try/install ubuntu" дошол. Правда, возможно, дисковод на ПК не читает формат диска (с дисководом были проблемы).
2. В БИОС захожу, но не могу прказать `Load Fail-Save Defaults` - на клаве сломана клавиша `Shift` (БИОС требует для подтверждения большую `Y`) (при работающем ПК я это компенсировал доп. клавишами), а клава в доме одна.

Comment: @Akina - добавил информацию про диск.

Comment: 1) Диск можно проверить попыткой загрузки с него на другом компьютере. Если загрузка прошла беспроблемно - проверен. Ну или есть QEmu, VirtualBox и протчая. 2) Зажать Alt, на доп. клавиатуре набрать 89, отпустить Alt.

Comment: @Akina 1) диск к сожалению отказался работаь через 5 минут - сделал флушку ибо обнаружил в настройках BIOS что можно выбрать для загрузки USB
2) Возвращать настройки к заводских не буду - диск у же восстановил, скоро напишу решение (хочу убедится что ПК проработает нормально дольше 5 минут)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету @Akina попробовал вынуть `SSD` - `BIOS` обнаружил все пречие девайсы и сказал что нет что запускать.

Далее создал загрузочную флешку с `Ubuntu 16.04`. Запускаю ПК с **отключенным** `SSD` и выбираю `Try Ubuntu`. Когда загружается, запускаю  `gparted` и подключаю обратно `SSD`. Форматирую. Устанавливаю `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Answer (score -1):

Мой рецепт восстановления загрузки:

Способ 1: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/ -- можно запустить LiveXP и в нем запустить программы для восстановления и редактирования.

Способ 2: Я брал диск с Windiows Vista и запускал восстановление системы, в моем случае смог восстановить загрузку Вин8 (чего диск вин8 или Heron'sCD сделать не смогли).

Лучшая программа для редактирования и восстановления разделов - EaseUS Partition Master, для добавления разделов Линукс меню загрузки использую EasyBCD.

Например, при помощи LiveCD и Partition Master Data Recovery восстанавливаете разделы. Затем, с Partition Master Partitions Manager делаете разделы как нужно и ставите ОС...

Comment: а может, хоть написать бы нужно, за что минус то?

Comment: Ну скорее всего за то, что ответ никак не соотносится с вопросом. Полное впечатление, что "проходил мимо, увидел знакомые слова и не удержался". Извиняюсь за грубость... но вот скажи - чего стоят все твои советы, если комп при подключении девайса тупо ни с чего не грузится? или грузится - но только когда проблемный накопитель отключен...

Comment: ага,понятно,спасибо.
Ну, написанно,что разделы удалены были.Мой пост говорит как исправить их. Если с проблемным диском не грузится комп-без него грузим в лайвСД, комп в сон ставим,рискуем в таком состоянии его подключить (в резинПерчатках), исправляем его программно с ЛайвСД. Грубо, но я бы попробовал.
Свой пост удалю скоро, пусть еще чуть повесит, на всяк случай))

Comment: Ага... при условии что ось продолжит работу, конечно - но вот описанные симптомы позволяют скорее рассчитывать на глухой завис.

Comment: Кажется, у меня было подобное, вроде... "ПреОС выполняла действия, а затем заявила об ошибке" -- это говорит, что скорее всего MBR испорчен. Нужно обязательно загрузиться с DVD (или флешки) и восстановить испорченную таблицу на диске. Если очень грубо и рисковать - отключить проблемный, загрузиться с DVD,в этот же момент включить(физ.макс.осторожно!-есть риск).

Comment: @CodeGust - как ни странно но я пол часа сидел с открытым ПК и пробовал разные последовательности подключения SATA девайсов и когда использовал Ubuntu для форматирования диска подключал его непосредственно перед созданием новой таблици.